# Can anyone tell me the year of this Kona road bike?

Tags: road-bike

[image]Or any details! I know it is an older Kona bike and would like to sell, but would like to provide buyers with details. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a [2003 Kona Kona](http://www.bikepedia.com/QuickBike/BikeSpecs.aspx?year=2003&brand=Kona&model=Kona) to me.  Kona made the Kona until 2005 and then in 2006 they started the Zing line.  It's a very standard entry level "bike shop" road bike.  Assuming a lot of parts swap hasn't happened, that page should have most of the info.